# Cmd command to delete files without trash

Tags: windows, command, recycle-bin

Please do you know of a cmd command for windows 8, which deletes files directly from disk? Without sending them to trash?

I've tried 
del c:\something /q but it moves files into trash instead of deleting them permanently.

Comment: why downvote without any comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that when you right click on trash, you can disable trash on specific drive, or limit amount of space used by trash on drive.

This is actually what is good enough for me, but I'll keep the question open, so maybe someone answers the root of it.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, command "DEL" delete files without sending them to trash. From Microsoft official websit.

> If you use del to delete a file from your disk, you cannot retrieve it.

More detail in :[Docs for Del](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc771049(v=ws.11)#remarks)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18595946)

Comment: Thanks for review, and I have tried my best to fix it.

Comment: As you see, there are some upvotes on the question, so there are obviously people, who have experienced the same as me. It seems to me, that this problem is specific to the windows 8 version.